# Using Backbone to FETCH a model using the OPTION verb

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

I am using Backbone with a RESTful interface that is provided by a 3rd party (so I can not change it).

For one of the models (which is read only) the RESTful interface states that you use the HTTP OPTIONS verb not the GET verb. Can I tell backbone to use "OPTIONS" not "GET" just for that model as other models use GET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this in your model definition:

```
sync: function(method, model, options){
  if(method !== "read") throw "Read-only model cannot be called with non-read method";

  options || (options = {});
  var params = {type: "OPTIONS", dataType: 'json'};

  if (!options.url) {
    params.url = _.result(model, 'url') || urlError();
  }

  var xhr = options.xhr = Backbone.ajax(_.extend(, options));
  model.trigger('request', model, xhr, options);
  return xhr;
}
```

In opther words, you need to rewrite the `sync` method for your model so it behaves like you want it to (i.e. sending OPTIONS verb). Take a look at Backbone's `sync` implementation for inspiration: http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-143